# How to convert a sentence into first order logic?

Tags: predicate-logic

> There is a student who does not like punctual students.

Where,

S(x) = “x is student”

P(x) = “x is always punctual”

L(x, y) = “x likes y”

can please help me? Thanks Alot~~

Comment: Try [asking better questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) in the future. Also, one question mark is enough to make a question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exists x S(x), \forall y (S(y)\wedge P(y)) \longrightarrow \neg L(x,y)$$

This comes from:

"There is a student": $\exists x S(x)$

"Punctual studients": $\forall y(S(y) \wedge P(y))$ (Any $y$ that is both student and punctual)

"Does not like": $\neg L(x,y)$